# kafka + get Isr partial list + workaround solution

Tags: apache-kafka

We run the following command:

```
 /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 19.12.56.3:2181 --describe
```

> Note: `19.12.56.3` is the zookeeper ip

This prints a description of `kafka` brokers and `kafka` partitions.

We noticed that `ISR` is missing and that brokers id's are not balanced to `kafka` partitions:

example from topic - `list_manufacture_whine`

```
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 12   Leader: 1821    Replicas: 1824,1821,1822    Isr: 1821
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 13   Leader: 1825    Replicas: 1825,1822,1823    Isr: 1825,1823,1822
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 14   Leader: 1826    Replicas: 1826,1823,1824    Isr: 1826,1824,1823
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 15   Leader: 1821    Replicas: 1821,1824,1825    Isr: 1821
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 16   Leader: 1822    Replicas: 1822,1825,1826    Isr: 1822,1825,1826
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 17   Leader: 1821    Replicas: 1823,1826,1821    Isr: 1821
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 18   Leader: 1824    Replicas: 1824,1822,1823    Isr: 1822,1823,1824
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 19   Leader: 1825    Replicas: 1825,1823,1824    Isr: 1825,1824,1823
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 20   Leader: 1826    Replicas: 1826,1824,1825    Isr: 1826,1825,1824
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 21   Leader: 1821    Replicas: 1821,1825,1826    Isr: 1821
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 22   Leader: 1821    Replicas: 1822,1826,1821    Isr: 1821
Topic: list_manufacture_whine   Partition: 23   Leader: 1821    Replicas: 1823,1821,1822    Isr: 1821
```

When we restart the zookeepers server and all `kafka` brokers clusters, the ISR and `kafka` brokers balance.

How can we explain that?

How can we get the expected output without restarting zookeeper?

We tried performing `kafka` *reassignment partitions* but this did not help us.

Comment: Are you tracking JMX metrics for ISR shrinks? Look at logs for healthiness?

Comment: from the server.log and zookeeper servers logs its difficult to know why ISR is mising on some partitions , but what I can to tell you is after we fix MTU value on zookeeper serves that was MTU=9000 to MTU=1500 ( while MTU on kafka are 1500 ) and then we restart the zookeepers server and kafka servers then everything is ok

Comment: Jumbo Frames are primarily meant between datanodes and nodemanagers, not Kafka and Zookeeper

Comment: but if zookeeper server are set as MTU=9000 and kafka with MTU=1500 then this will cause very bad performance between kafka to zookeepers and also packet loss ( hope you agree witj me about this point )

Comment: Zookeeper doesn't need jumbo frames. The amount of data going to it is not that large. AFAIK, nowhere in either the Kafka, Zookeeper, or HDP/Cloudera docs does it say adjust MTU for anything but Hadoop processes (not HDP cluster wide)

Comment: not understand ,  what I am saying is that -  since zookeepers servr was with mtu that was diff from kafka , then we suspect -  this was the reason the zookeepers servers not sync to kafka - do you agree with my findings ??

Comment: Zookeeper doesn't track the ISR list. The brokers handle that themselves and communicate that to the Controller... If you suspect network latency is the issue, then are you actively capturing that data?

Comment: so how you explain that only restart of zookeeper and the kafka fix the issue with Isr and brokers balance ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206651/discussion-between-jessica-and-cricket-007).